Problem rendering Chinese Traditional characters in a Word document in mht format
I have created a doc (.doc) file, with MHT content (html tags and content) in it. The content consists of some Chinese Traditional characters in it along with English characters. When I try opening this using Microsoft Word, the Chinese characters get corrupted and are rendered using junk characters. However, if I place just 1 Chinese character in the very beginning, just after the  tag, the whole document is opening perfectly fine in Word. Any help on this please? Another point to note is that if I open the same in Mac, it opens fine, without having to add the Chinese character in the beginning.
Sample:
Not working doc:

---- lot of text here in English.....
.....
處理出
Working doc:
處理出
---- lot of text here in English.....
.....
處理出

"I have created a doc (.doc)" - How did you create this doc? Is this a programming-related question? Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

No, this is not a program related one. I have edited it in Notepad.

Then this question is off-topic here on StackOverflow

This question belongs on [su] as a general Word usage question. This site is strictly for questions related to programming. If you're using Word VBA, your question is appropriate for SO. If not, it belongs on [su]. For more information about what is acceptable to ask here, see the [help].

When the encoding is not explicitly specified, Windows and Microsoft Word will try to automatically detect the document's encoding. This detection mechanism can sometimes be inaccurate, especially if the document mainly contains English characters with only a few non-Latin characters.
By adding a Chinese character at the beginning of the document, you explicitly signal the encoding detection mechanism that the document contains non-Latin characters. This makes Word more likely to use a universal encoding (such as UTF-8) to display these characters correctly.
try this solution
Choose text encoding when you open and save files - Microsoft Support

Please refrain from answering off-topic questions; we do not want to encourage them.
